# "Maison" meaning?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

The word's context is when a pastry chef describes he once ***ai travaillé dans de belles maisons*** and he especially loved working in ***une maison parisienne***, where recipe didn't live up to his expectation though. I have searched and figure out it should be a place or a firm in quite rare context, but I do not know if it should be some places where a pastry chef works. I would love to know more about this word, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Maison* can be used indeed as a synonym for a firm or an enterprise. It carries a positive connotation, and some prestigious businesses take pride in being called a "maison".

It can be used for restaurants or caterers as you have found out, but also for some other types of business, such as in fashion (eg *La maison Dior*), or even for some "mom-and-pop" stores (this is where the shop is then usually named after the family, eg a grocerer named Dupont can christen his/her store *maison Dupont*).

Even outside of these usual areas of business, it is also common in phrases used to talk about years of service in a firm:

> Il a vingt ans de maison (he has been working here for 20 years)

In large firms, the corporate seat can also be called *la maison-mère*.

Publishers can be also be called *maison d'édition* (ex: *la maison d'édition Larousse*)

Comment: In English compare to "software house", also perfume and fashion companies tend to refer to themselves as houses.